# Android: GridView shows all but a few images

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have 6 images downloaded [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoJsu.png), but the GridView in my gallery only displays 5 of those [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToUi0.png).

I'm trying to copy how Instagram displays its gallery, with a selected image taking up 60% of the screen and the gallery images taking up the rest.

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutl">
        <!--toolbar-->
        <include layout="@layout/snippet_top_gallerybar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutl">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/galleryImageView"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40">
        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:verticalSpacing="1.5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1.5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="none"
            android:id="@+id/gridView">

        </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I created a square view to generate square cells

layout_grid_imageview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.example.sheldon.instagramclone.Util.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridViewImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridProgressBar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GalleryFragment.java

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 4;
private ImageView mExit;
private Spinner mSpinner;
private TextView mNext;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private List<String> directories;
private GridView mGridView;
private ImageView mGalleryImage;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> directoryToImage;
private String append = "file:/";
private String mSelectedImage;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    mExit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.exitShare);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.shareSpinner);
    mNext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shareNext);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mGalleryImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
    mExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Navigating to next step in sharing photo");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected_image", mSelectedImage);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    init();

    return view;
}

private void init() {
    ImageFinder imageFinder = new ImageFinder();
    imageFinder.getImages(getActivity());
    directoryToImage = imageFinder.getImageMapping();
    directories = new ArrayList<>(directoryToImage.keySet());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, directories);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected: " + directories.get(position));
            setUpGridView(directories.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void setUpGridView(String directory) {
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLS = directoryToImage.get(directory);
    Log.d(TAG, "setUpGridView: Displaying " + directory + "  with " + imgURLS.size() + " images");
    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth / NUM_COLUMNS;
    Log.d(TAG, "setUpGridView: Image Width is " + imageWidth);
    mGridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, append, imgURLS);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imgURLS.get(0),mGalleryImage, mProgressBar, append);
    mSelectedImage = imgURLS.get(0);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imgURLS.get(position), mGalleryImage, mProgressBar, append);
        mSelectedImage = imgURLS.get(0);
    }
});}
```

I display the images using a library called Universal Image loader

GridImageAdapter.java

```
public class GridImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int layoutResource;
private String mAppend;
private ArrayList<String> imgURLs;

public GridImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, String append, ArrayList<String> imgURLs) {
    super(context, layoutResource, imgURLs);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
    mAppend = append;
    this.imgURLs = imgURLs;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    SquareImageView image;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridProgressBar);
        holder.image = (SquareImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String imgURL = getItem(position);
    Log.d(TAG, "getView: Loading position " + position + ", displaying " + imgURL + ", with image " + holder.image);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage(mAppend + imgURL, holder.image, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            if(holder.mProgressBar != null){
                holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            if(holder.mProgressBar != null){
                holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if(holder.mProgressBar != null){
                holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            if(holder.mProgressBar != null){
                holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

First time posting, so I apologize if there's anything wrong with this post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, when you ask a question we expect that you find the general code that is breaking the function and we can help you from there. So check your project and see what part is not working. Are all images being received before displaying on screen? Is the sixth image existent in the grid but not displaying? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being so general and unclear in my post, I wasn't quite sure which portion of the code was the problem area. After looking over the code again, I noticed a stupid mistake. I set GridView's numColumns attribute to 5 in fragment_gallery.xml, but calculated the column width in GalleryFragment.java using private static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 4. I assume that this caused images to be displayed in a non-existent 5th column.